# Unit testing can't find button and it equal to null

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am trying to do an unit testing for a reuseable component, the reuseable componet have an input and output. But It seem to can't find the button class. and also if there is a way, is thhere a way to not use fixture.

the error =TypeError: Cannot read properties of null

```
describe('SelectorComponent', () => {
  let component: SelectorComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SelectorComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    component = new SelectorComponent();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SelectorComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it('should select a dimension when clicked', () => {
    let selectors: Selector[] = [{
      id: '1', 
      name: 'Child ',
      parent: 'Parent ',
      sortOrder: 1,
      icon: 'brain',
      selected: true, 
      children: []
    }];
    spyOn(component, 'selectSelector');
    component.selectors = selectors;
    let btn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.selectors'));
    btn.triggerEventHandler('click', null); 
    fixture.detectChanges();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.selectorSelected.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

```
@Input() public selectors!: Selector[];
  @Output() public selectoSelected = new EventEmitter<Dimension>();

  constructor() { }

  selectselectors(selector: Selector) {
    this.selectoSelected.emit(selector);
  }
```

```
<button
    class="selector"
    (click)="selectselectors(selectors)"
    *ngFor="let selector of selectors"
>
    <div class="name">{{ selector.name }}</div>
</button>
```

Thank you in advance, I am new with Unit testing

I have try without fixture alsso, but it didnt seem to work, it keep sayying button is null

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find your button with the class **selectors** `By.css('.selectors')` but your button has only the class **selector** (without s at the end) `<button class="selector"`

So you have to remove your typo from By.css and change it to `By.css('.selector')`

Edit:

If you add `fixture.detectChanges();` after adding your selectors into your component (`component.selectors = selectors;`), your button get rendererd. Thats because ngFor dosent show any buttons without the array.

You are using `spyOn(component, 'selectSelector');` but your Component only have `selectselectors` (Typo)

You are using `expect(component.selectorSelected.emit)` but your Component only have `selectoSelected` (Typo)

Comment: I have tried that, and it still didn't work

Comment: @JuliePham I edit my answer and found some typos. I dont know if you fixed them already but you can look again.

Comment: Is there a way without using fixture?

Comment: Is there any issue with fixture? Even angular use fixture and detectChanges to trigger initial bindings.
See: https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-with-inputs-and-outputs